# Is it possible in Camel to set different request timeout for each message send to ActiveMQ?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have a Request/Reply with ActiveMQ processing Camel Route where the time needed to process a message is different depending on the message. Is it possible to set the requestTimeout inside of the Camel exchange instead of in the route definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

What is your use-case for using different timeouts?
We could look into adding such functionality to camel-jms.

Comment: I have a queue in which a Master puts tasks. Tasks are routed to asynchronous processors that work in parallel. I have several types of tasks where each type completes in a widely ranging period of time (e.g. one type of task takes 5 minutes, other task takes few hours). I used to create a different route for each type of tasks, so that I could set the `requestTimeout`-option for each type.